# Using gitlab-ci to build .NET Core projects in docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, .net-core, gitlab-ci

I want to automate my deployment process using gitlab-ci. I'm doing so manually via ssh at the moment. The steps are:

Build:

- dotnet restore
- dotnet publish

This leaves me with a directory full of .dlls. I want to deploy these to a docker container, so I run:

- docker build
- docker stop
- docker rm
- docker run

However, I'm having a hard time finding the proper way to do both in the same `.gitlab.ci.yml` file.

I need the dotnet tooling from `microsoft/dotnet:latest` and the docker cli tools from `docker:latest`.

I tried having two stages based on each of these images, but the output is not shared. To solve this, I tried using `artifact`, but that fails to upload.

I can't find any examples of this online, so I wonder if I'm doing something that shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why you're doing `docker run` in your build pipeline, nor why `artifact` doesn't work. We're doing this exact thing in to stages with `artifact` and `dependencies`.

It's anyway quite normal to have to customize build images in order to fit your needs. For your build image it seems like you need `docker` alongside `dotnet`. Create a `Dockerfile` which you'll use as your build image, and let it inherit from `microsoft/dotnet`. Then install `docker` in that image. Remember to mount in `/var/run/docker.sock` so that the container can use the docker daemon.

Your new `Dockerfile` will look like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet

RUN echo deb http://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list && \
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y docker-engine
```

To run the image on your computer you use

```
docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock yournewimage
```

You configure GitLab to mount `/var/run/docker.sock` in the runner configuration file, then you can use the new image in your `gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: I'm actually not using docker run at the moment as I got stuck on the artifact problem. But eventually, I want my CI pipeline to deploy the image on each commit to master.
I will definitely try your Dockerfile. Even with artifacts working, I think I might prefer this solution. I'm a bit busy at the moment, but I will get back to you (and accept your answer if it works) in a few days.

Comment: Thanks for the Dockerfile. That part worked like a charm. I had to alter my config as described here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1905
I raised an issue with the artifacts. I mistakenly thought each step could continue where the last one left off as long as it were the same image.

Comment: Just getting back to this. I newer directly solved the issue as I found a workaround. I do however suspect that gitlab behind nginx is the problem with artifacts, and that increasing the request limit of nginx may solve this issue.